How can I merge multiple financial statements into a single dataframe, only by locations?
I've been trying to merge mutliple financial statements, without sacrificing line items, and merging all the items along with the years amnd year's value to get the a larger statement with this items and years. I've tried a few aprproach but I'm very rookie at coding, I export the dataframes (BALANCE SHEETS) for ilustration purposes. https://1drv.ms/f/c/175d836e30c91f0a/Ep80w4-k929ElYJ_NIcFa4sB8Bwm3JgZYTCDz_b0XKx3BQ?e=MXHRuI
This is what I've tried so far:
import pandas as pd
from filing_scraper import scrape_and_process

# Call the function to get the dataframes stored in a list
categories_dict = scrape_and_process()

# List of headers to process
headers = ["Consolidated Balance Sheets", "Consolidated Statements of Operations", "Consolidated Statements of Cash Flows"]

def try_merge(ls_dfs, key_col):
    # Ensure all dataframes have the key column as the first column
    for idx, df in enumerate(ls_dfs):
        if key_col in df.columns:
            cols = [key_col] + [col for col in df.columns if col != key_col]
            df = df[cols]
        df.columns = [f"{col}_{idx}" if col != key_col else col for col in df.columns]
        ls_dfs[idx] = df
    
    final_df = ls_dfs[0]
    for i in ls_dfs[1:]:
        final_df = pd.merge(final_df, i, on=key_col, how='outer')
    
    # Combine duplicate columns (if any) after merge
    col_sets = set(final_df.columns)
    for col in col_sets:
        if col.endswith('_0'):
            base_col = col.rsplit('_', 1)[0]
            col_variants = [f"{base_col}_{idx}" for idx in range(len(ls_dfs)) if f"{base_col}_{idx}" in final_df.columns]
            combined_series = final_df[col_variants[0]]
            for variant in col_variants[1:]:
                combined_series = combined_series.combine_first(final_df[variant])
            final_df[base_col] = combined_series
            final_df.drop(columns=col_variants, inplace=True)
    
    return final_df


merged_dfs = {}

for header in headers:
    if header in categories_dict:
        dataframes = categories_dict[header]
        if dataframes:  # Check if the list is not empty
            refined_data = try_merge(dataframes, "Keys")
            refined_data = refined_data.dropna(axis=0, how="all").dropna(axis=1, how="all")
            merged_dfs[header] = refined_data


for header, df in merged_dfs.items():
    print(f"Merged DataFrame for {header}:\n", df)

